# Azure Sentinel Contributor Role is not available in Administrative Roles on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

According to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/roles#azure-sentinel-specific-roles), there should be 3 built in roles for azure sentinel. However, a global admin account is unable to see any of them in Administrative Roles on Azure.

Comment: The roles might have been renamed to Microsoft Sentinel *

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the underlying workspace, in the `Access Control (IAM)` blade, I can set the roles:
[image: Add role assignment Azure Sentinel]

They do not appear in the Azure AD roles list indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you go the the resource group that your instance of Sentinal is in it will have a 'Access Control' link.
From there you can click 'Add role assignment'

[image]

Choose which role you wish to assign and press next
[image: choose the role]

Then assign access to a user or group

[image: assign user]